# 2D Matrix barcode generate wrong barcode for dynamic string in tcpdf vendor in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, barcode, tcpdf

I need to generate 2D Matrix Barcode using TCPDF vendor in cakephp. But **write2DBarcode** generate wrong barcode.

I have generate string dynamically for it, and passing it to write2DBarcode function. my string is

> A|3720001373|372aaaadS0|CC|826|B33 8TH|001|001||Chetan|Panchal||Abu
>   Dhabi||Ballingarry|123456|20130508170546-863|229894|4000|
>   |

string have 304 fix characters, so i have add spaces and last character '|' after '229894|4000|' for complete 304 characters as per the requirement. TCPDF generate matrix code but when i decode that Matrix code using Barcode Reader, its display only below string without spaces and last '|'

> A|3720001373|372aaaadS0|CC|826|B33 8TH|001|001||Chetan|Panchal||Abu
>   Dhabi||Ballingarry|123456|20130508170546-863|229894|4000|

If i pass string static then its generate perfect barcode. can anyone suggest me what is the issue with Barcode generator? or issue with my string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes some barcode reader not working proper. you have to use another barcode reader for that. write2DBarcode generate always perfect barcode. try another barcode reader.